# What is the equation for a freely propogating glueball?

Tags: standard-model, gluons

What is the equation for a freely propogating glueball? Can glueball dissipate into heat? What is the lifetime of glueball?
Does glueball obtain a mass somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist no free gluons, it is called [confinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon#Confinement):

> Since gluons themselves carry color charge, they participate in strong interactions. These gluon-gluon interactions constrain color fields to string-like objects called "flux tubes", which exert constant force when stretched. Due to this force, quarks are confined within composite particles called hadrons. This effectively limits the range of the strong interaction to 1×10^−15 meters, roughly the size of an atomic nucleus. Beyond a certain distance, the energy of the flux tube binding two quarks increases linearly

Only color neutral objects exist for larger dimensions and the gluons carry color.

[Glue-balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball) in larger dimensions than 10^-15 meters should  color neutral and are composed of hadrons.

> In particle physics, a glueball (also gluonium, gluon-ball) is a hypothetical composite particle. It consists solely of gluon particles, without valence quarks. Such a state is possible because gluons carry color charge and experience the strong interaction. Glueballs are extremely difficult to identify in particle accelerators, because they mix with ordinary meson states.

The lifetime of a glueball is very short because by the time it is out of the 10^-15 cm range of the hadroninc interaction creating it, it has already formed into hadrons i.e. pions kaons etc. It has the invariant mass of the hadrons that it has decayed into. Within the nuclear range it is the invariant mass of the sum of the fourvectors of the gluons that compose it.

Please read the links provided.